# Examples of "undoable" applicative functors?

Tags: haskell, undo, applicative, alternative-functor

I declared a group on applicative functors. Judging by what we usually call "actions", it seems that such group would enable the action to be **undone**:

```
import Control.Applicative

class Alternative f => Undoable f where
    undo :: f a -> f a
```

Being a group, for all `x :: Undoable f => f a`, the following laws shall satisfy:

```
x <|> undo x ≡ empty
undo x <|> x ≡ empty
```

Some instances:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Functor.Compose
import Data.Functor.Product
import Data.Proxy

instance Undoable Proxy where
    undo _ = Proxy

instance (Undoable f, Applicative g) => Undoable (Compose f g) where
    undo (Compose x) = Compose (undo x)

instance (Undoable f, Undoable g) => Undoable (Product f g) where
    undo (Pair x y) = Pair (undo x) (undo y)

instance Undoable m => Undoable (Kleisli m a) where
    undo (Kleisli f) = Kleisli (undo . f)
```

At least for me, these instances are of no interest. Some non-instances include:

- `Maybe`: Once successful, it will be always a success regardless of other options.
- `[]` and `ZipList`: Options always add nondeterminism, not subtract from it.

  - `ReadP` and `ReadPrec`: As implied by above.
- `IO`: Taken literally, this instance would be a time machine. Even though we may take the quotient of the reality over time-space, there is a practical counterexample: A new `IORef` cannot be forgotten.

Is there any particularly interesting instance of `Undoable`?

Answer (score 7):

I would consider something like this. Not a `Prelude.Functor` because the keys need to be orderable (could also be `Hashable` or only `Eq`, you know the tradeoffs).

It's basically a multiset that allows negative multiplicities. *Antimatter elements* as it were.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Prelude as Hask
import Data.List (sortOn)
import Control.Category.Constrained.Prelude
import Control.Arrow.Constrained
import Control.Applicative.Constrained

data Dirac n k = Dirac { getOccurences :: Map.Map k n }

instance Real n => Functor (Dirac n) (Ord⊢(->)) (->) where
  fmap (ConstrainedMorphism f) (Dirac m)
    = Dirac . Map.fromAscList
            . concatMap (\((k,n₀):grp) -> case sum $ n₀ : map snd grp of
                     0 -> []
                     μ -> [(k,μ)] )
            . groupBy (comparing fst)
            . sortOn fst
            . map (first f)
            $ Map.toList m
```

with

```
instance Num n => Undoable (Dirac n) where
  undo (Dirac m) = Dirac $ Map.map negate m
```

I think there can be a conforming `Applicative` / `Alternative` built around this, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Does a list-like `Applicative` instance work? i.e. thinking of `Map k n` as a list of `k`s, each with multiplicity `n`, we get a fairly natural "cartesian product, then multiply the `n`s to get the output multiplicity" kind of thing that's consistent with the existing list instance. Then I would suppose `Alternative` is `unionWith (+)`.

Comment: You could consider `Map.filter (0/=) . Map.mapKeysWith (+) f` for your `fmap`.

Answer (score 6):

Any monoid can be lifted to an `Alternative`:

```
newtype ViaMonoid m a = ViaMonoid m

instance Monoid m => Applicative (ViaMonoid m) where
    pure _ = ViaMonoid mempty
    ViaMonoid f <*> ViaMonoid x = ViaMonoid (f <> x)

instance Monoid m => Alternative (ViaMonoid m) where
    empty = ViaMonoid mempty
    ViaMonoid m <|> ViaMonoid m' = ViaMonoid (m <> m')
```

Any group can be lifted to `Undo`:

```
class Monoid g => Group g where
    -- law: g <> inverse g = inverse g <> g = mempty
    inverse :: g -> g

instance Group g => Undoable (ViaMonoid g) where
    undo (ViaMonoid m) = ViaMonoid (inverse m)
```

`ViaMonoid` is also known by the more traditional name `Const`, and is used to good effect in e.g. `lens` and friends.